# Bolt-CMS keeps logging me out after a period of time

Tags: config, logout, silex, bolt-cms

I am using **Bolt-CMS** in my project and every ten minutes Bolt logs me out from the CMS. Even if I am active and on the root account.

- I know I use Bolt version **3.2.13**
- And that bolt runs on Silex. (with some Symfony components)
- And I presume there is a config file for this.

So does anyone know where to find this config file or where I can turn the automatic logout off?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bolt is built on Silex not Symfony, whereas Silex uses symfony's [HTTP Fondation component](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation) (and others symfony components like form, security, csrf and so on)

Comment: oh eeh. oops, thanks for pointing that out @V-Light

Comment: Did you check the lifetime of the session cookie? (assuming you're using session cookies). Also check where are your sessions stored, it may be that a cron job is deleting the session files in the default folder ([this](https://serverfault.com/questions/511609/why-does-debian-clean-php-sessions-with-a-cron-job-instead-of-using-phps-built) might be relevant to your case)

Comment: mTorres. I have been in the dev chat of Bolt. and I got the same answer. It did delete cookie files but they were still active so I had to delete them manually. can you put your comment in an answer bevouse it is the solution? ( also shoutout to Gawain for helping me on other forums! )

Comment: Done! PS: To reply a message, add the @ symbol before the user name, I did not receive your reply :-)

Comment: @mTorres oh ye I see. thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should do is check the lifetime of your cookie (check the developer toolbar of your browser).

If this does not give a clue, then most likely there is a cron job that deletes your cookie files on the server. [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/511609/why-does-debian-clean-php-sessions-with-a-cron-job-instead-of-using-phps-built) might be relevant in this scenario.

Comment: You were correct Bolt saved the cookies somewhere on their end and I could not find it. But i found them so it where the cookies.